# Falha ao Substituir ID por Nome de Equipes PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, json

Estou consumindo um Web Service em php, criei uma função pra comparar campeonatos e me retornar o id das equipes que jogarão ou vão jogar, em outra url, tenho o nome das equipes e os ids das mesmas, estou tentando comparar o id das equipes que estão nos jogos com o das equipes da URL e substituir o ID pelo nome, mas não está funcionando, saberiam me dizer onde estou errando?

**URLs**

```
<?php
// pega os valores da primeira URL
$api_campeonatos = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
$campeonatos = wp_remote_get( $api_campeonatos );
$campeonato = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $campeonatos ), true );

// pega os valores da segunda URL
$api_resultados = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/resultados?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
$resultados = wp_remote_get( $api_resultados );
$resultado = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $resultados ), true );

$api_equipes = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/equipes?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL';
$equipes = wp_remote_get( $api_equipes );
$equipe = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $equipes ), true );

$retorno_resultados = array();
```

**Filtra as equipes dos jogos de um campeonato específico:**

```
foreach($campeonato as $camp){
    foreach($resultado as $result){
        if(!is_array($result)){

        }else{
            if(isset($camp['codigo']) && isset($result['campeonato']) && $camp['codigo'] == $result['campeonato']){
                $retorno_resultados[$result['campeonato']][] = array(
                    'mandante' => $result['mandante'], 
                    'visitante' => $result['visitante'],
                    'nm_mandante' => '',
                    'nm_visitante' => '',
                    'id' => $camp['codigo'],
                    'data' => $result['data'],
                    'placar1n' => $result['placar1n'],
                    'placar2n' => $result['placar2n'],
                    'placar1p' => $result['placar1p'],
                    'placar2p' => $result['placar2p'],
                    'placar1s' => $result['placar1s'],
                    'placar2s' => $result['placar2s']
                ); // <--- adiciona
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

**Substituí o ID pelo nome procurando nas URLs "RESULTADOS" e "EQUIPES":**

```
foreach($retorno_resultados as $a){
    foreach($a as $result){
        $mandante = '';
        $visitante = '';
        foreach($equipe as $role){
            if(!is_array($role)){
                    //$retorno = $retorno.'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
            }else{
                if($role['codigo'] == $result['mandante']){
                    //$retorno_equipes[] = array('mandante' => '<td>'.$role['nome'].'</td>', 'visitante' => $role['nome']); // <--- adiciona
                    $result['nm_mandante'] = $role['nome'];
                    //echo $result['nm_mandante'];
                }

                if($role['codigo'] == $result['visitante']){
                    $result['nm_visitante'] = $role['nome'];
                    //echo $role['nome'];
                }
            }   
        }
        //echo 'chegou';
        //$result['nm_mandante'] = $mandante;
        //$result['nm_visitante'] = $visitante;
    }
}
```

**Printa o conteúdo na div:**

```
<script>

$(function(){

    <?php foreach($retorno_resultados as $val){ ?>

    var html3 = '';
    var id='';

    <?php foreach($val as $res){ ?>

    html3 += '<tr><td><?php echo $res['nm_mandante'];?>x<?php echo $res['nm_visitante'];?></td></tr>';
    id = <?php echo $res['id'] ?>;


    <?php } ?>
    $('#cont-'+id).html(html3);
    <?php } ?>

});

</script>
```

**Retorno JSON URL:resultados:**

```
{
"codigo": "31",
"campeonato": "18",
"data": "2018-09-11 00:00:00",
"horario": "19H",
"local": "2",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "5",
"visitante": "3",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "2",
"obs": null
},
  {
"codigo": "32",
"campeonato": "18",
"data": "2018-09-25 00:00:00",
"horario": "19H",
"local": "4",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "7",
"visitante": "3",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "4",
"obs": null
},
  {
"codigo": "25",
"campeonato": "19",
"data": "2018-08-13 00:00:00",
"horario": "19h",
"local": "9",
"realizada": "N",
"jogo": "0",
"fase": "2",
"rodada": "0",
"mandante": "2",
"visitante": "6",
"placar1n": null,
"placar2n": null,
"placar1p": null,
"placar2p": null,
"placar1s": null,
"placar2s": null,
"grupo1": "",
"grupo2": "",
"quadra": "9",
"obs": null
},
```

**Retorno JSON URL:equipes:**

```
 {
"codigo": "1",
"nome": "Arbos Santo André",
"nomeabreviado": "ARBOS SA",
"url": "arbos-santo-andre",
"telefone": "",
"email": "",
"endereco": "",
"complemento": null,
"bairro": "",
"cidade": "",
"uf": "",
"cep": ""
},
  {
"codigo": "2",
"nome": "Arbos São Bernardo do Campo",
"nomeabreviado": "ARBOS SBC",
"url": "arbos-sao-bernardo-do-campo",
"telefone": "",
"email": "",
"endereco": "",
"complemento": null,
"bairro": "",
"cidade": "",
"uf": "",
"cep": ""
},
  {
"codigo": "16",
"nome": "Arbos São Caetano do Sul",
"nomeabreviado": "ARBOS SCS",
"url": "arbos-sao-caetano-do-sul",
"telefone": "",
"email": "",
"endereco": "",
"complemento": null,
"bairro": "",
"cidade": "",
"uf": "",
"cep": ""
},
  {
"codigo": "23",
"nome": "Barão - Mauá",
"nomeabreviado": "B. MAUÁ",
"url": "barao--maua",
"telefone": "",
"email": "",
"endereco": "rua onze de junho, 166",
"complemento": null,
"bairro": "jd do pilar",
"cidade": "maua",
"uf": "SP",
"cep": "09360-010"
},
  {
"codigo": "5",
"nome": "Barão SBC",
"nomeabreviado": "BAR",
"url": "barao-sbc",
"telefone": "",
"email": "",
"endereco": "",
"complemento": null,
"bairro": "",
"cidade": "",
"uf": "",
"cep": ""
},
```

OBS: EXISTEM MAIS REGISTROS DE RETORNO, MAS É MUITO EXTENSO.

Comment: Qual erro é mostrado?

Comment: ele não retorna erro, só está trazendo um retorno vazio pelo que parece

Comment: Coloque o resultado das APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de criar um outro `foreach` apenas para pesquisar os nomes das equipes, é mais fácil fazer isso no momento em que você está criando o array, usando duas funcionalidades do php. Que são o `array_search` para pesquisar um valor e obter a chave, e `array_column` para trazer uma lista de valores de determinada coluna do array.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
$colunas =  array_column($equipe, 'codigo'); // <-- pega todos os valores da coluna 'codigo'

foreach($campeonato as $camp){
    foreach($resultado as $result){
        if(!is_array($result)){

        }else{


            // pesquisa chave do mandante
            $key1 = array_search($result['mandante'],$colunas);
            $mandante = $equipe[$key1]['nome']; // <-- pega o valor

            // pesquisa chave do visitante
            $key2 = array_search($result['visitante'], $colunas);
            $visitante = $equipe[$key2]['nome']; // <-- pega o valor

            if(isset($camp['codigo']) && isset($result['campeonato']) && $camp['codigo'] == $result['campeonato']){
                $retorno_resultados[$result['campeonato']][] = array(
                    'mandante' => $result['mandante'], 
                    'visitante' => $result['visitante'],
                    'nm_mandante' => $mandante,
                    'nm_visitante' => $visitante,
                    'id' => $camp['codigo'],
                    'data' => $result['data'],
                    'placar1n' => $result['placar1n'],
                    'placar2n' => $result['placar2n'],
                    'placar1p' => $result['placar1p'],
                    'placar2p' => $result['placar2p'],
                    'placar1s' => $result['placar1s'],
                    'placar2s' => $result['placar2s']
                ); // <--- adiciona
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: os valores ainda retornam em branco, eu preciso alterar alguma coisa na chamada do jQuery?

Comment: deu certo!!! troquei o array no jquery.

Comment: muito obrigado de novo cara! você é show

Comment: Isso! Ai depois você usa no jquery!

Comment: @MiguelCampos sem problema!

Comment: @MiguelCampos fiz uma edição que fará seu código ficar com mais performance. Aconselho você a usar desta forma que está agora.

Comment: perfeito Andrei!

Comment: te enviei um e-mail com uma dúvida